# Moving PyCharm projects folder and keeping reference to python interpreter

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm using macOS 10.15.4 and PyCharm 2019.3.4

I currently have a folder inside the PyCharmProjects folder (that is automatically created when PyCharm first runs) where I keep projects for a class. I want to move this folder, which contains multiple other folders which each contain PyCharm projects, somewhere else on my computer (like the Desktop). The problem is if I move the folder (or even just a single PyCharm project) the next time I open the project in PyCharm, it says "Invalid python interpreter selected for the project." Now I can manually go into PyCharm preferences and point it to the new location I moved the folder so it can use the correct python interpreter. But this would be tedious to do for every single project I have. (And yes, every project I have uses its own interpreter and virtual environment.)

Is then a way I can move a folder containing multiple PyCharm projects without loosing the references to each of their respective python interpreters?

(Feel free to reword this question or the title.)

Comment: Since 2020.1 (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-40448) there should be an ability to select inner venv in one click, please give it a try. It will create new interpreters inside PyCharm, previous ones will be invalidated and can be removed in `File - Setting - Project - Project Interpreter - Show All in the combo box`

Answer (score 0):

`PyCharm` uses configurations from your home directory. The [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#778017b8) say

```
macOS﻿

    Configuration

    ~/Library/Preferences/<PRODUCT><VERSION>
    Caches

    ~/Library/Caches/<PRODUCT><VERSION>
    Plugins

    ~/Library/Application Support/<PRODUCT><VERSION>
    Logs

    ~/Library/Logs/<PRODUCT><VERSION>

where <PRODUCT> is PyCharm.
```

They are `xml` files. Among them also a list of configured interpreters. They are separate because they are available for all your projects to be chosen as the default interpreter. You'll have to edit the `xml` files.

Comment: Again, this seems like a workaround. I can't believe PyCharm wouldn't have a feature that makes it easier to move a simple folder containing a project.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason PyCharm does not help with a moved virtualenv directory directly. (see comment from engineer: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-32435#focus=Comments-27-3139072.0-0)

On the upside, everything else seems to work, except the path to the venv python. That one can be changed through preferences/project preferences/python interpreter. Just click on "add", "existing", and select the python compiler in your project folder.

[image]

Try not to select the ".virtualenvs" python compiler, as if you fumble like I did, it seems it's a bit of a pain to get rid of it and go back to the right one. If you do that, renaming the project folder once more gets you back to square one and you get to try again.

*Note that I'm using MacOS. YMMV.*